# Excel VBA - Finding values in Columns and copy/pasteing them in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following data. How can I code in VBA to execute the following?

E: I know it would be something with Looping, i.e: For Next.

But I am having troubles to loop the values that are not blank, in EACH column to the **last column of the excel**

Before:
[image: http://imgur.com/XT0Lt7m]

After:
[image: http://imgur.com/x1qL46L]

Comment: You need to show us what you have already tried to do

Comment: If you're asking for help in starting coding this, I would recommend looking at loops to go the data you want copied.  The pasting should straightforward, with the recommendation to just past everything in, then delete the blank cells.  Good luck!

Comment: I have just edited my post to make it clear in terms of what I am needing. Thank you

Comment: @FranciscoJurado data is present just in 3 columns? G, H and I?

Comment: @GowthamShiva Not necessarily. I found out that data can be in any column until the last excel column. So I believe the looping would need to be done until the last column.

Comment: @FranciscoJurado But does it start only at column G and you want it in F?

Comment: @GowthamShiva Yes. It would loop from column G until the last column of the excel. And data should only be pasted in F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this VBA macro in your sheet,

```
Sub copyvalues()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
k = 1
'Change the value to 200 to the last row number of your range
For i = 1 To 200
    For j = 7 To 255
        If Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
            Range("F" & k).Value = Cells(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```